# Get Table Row Text With Spaces Between Table Datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, html-table

I have a html table that I am trying to build a search function for. My regex should find any table row, that has a word starting with text from a search bar.

I believe the regex is spot on, but have discovered the issue is actually in the tr.text() portion. Using .text() mashes the text of each td, in the tr together. This prevents "start of word" search for every column, and only works on words that are followed by a space.

Now I realize the easiest way to solve this is to insert a space via markup. But I am afraid this will change the layout of the table.

Is there a way to get the text of a tr, but divide the child td's text (preferably with a space)?

**EDIT:** Below is a code sample of my predicament.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search...">

<table>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 TextA</td>
        <td>Column2TextA</td>
        <td>Colum3A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 Text B</td>
        <td>Column2TextB</td>
        <td>Colum3B</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

JS:

```
var $rows = $('tr.searchable');

var val = '^(\\b' + ('#search').val().replace(/\.|@, '') + ')',
    reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
    text;

$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\.|@, '');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();
```

If I console.log(text), it logs something like:

```
Column1 TextAColumn2TextAColumn3A
Column1 TextBColumn2TextBColumn3B
```

So my search from "start of word" only (somewhat) works if you search for "Column1" (or any characters from start to end), or "TextA"/"TextB" (or any characters from start to end of both).

**RE-EDIT** So, my problem is that I can't search for Column2TextA or Column3A or Column3TextB or Column3B. Because .text() mashes them together, and thus doesn't see each of these as their own word for the \b in the regex to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the cells for each row and reduce them based on the RegExp test then return the truthy/falsey value of the length results.

If there are no cells matching the RegExp, its containing row will remain in the results, otherwise it will be removed.

Once it has filtered all of the rows, it will hide the remaining rows.

```js
var $rows = $('tr.searchable');

$('#search').on('input',function(){
    $rows.show();
    if(!this.value) return;
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value.replace(/\.|@/g,''), 'i');
    $rows.filter(function() {
        return !$('td', this).filter(function() {
            return reg.test(this.textContent.replace(/\.|@/g, ''));
        }).length;
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search...">
<table>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 TextA</td>
        <td>Column2TextA</td>
        <td>Colum3A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 Text B</td>
        <td>Column2TextB</td>
        <td>Colum3B</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

If you *really* want to just add a space before each table cell's text before testing it, then you can do it like this. This method just seems dirty to me, so I would not recommend this method.

```js
var $rows = $('tr.searchable');
$('td', $rows).prepend(' ');

$('#search').on('input',function(){
    $rows.show();
    if(!this.value) return;
    var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + this.value.replace(/\.|@/g,''), 'i');
    $rows.filter(function() {
        return !reg.test(this.textContent.replace(/\.|@/g, ''));
    }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search...">
<table>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 TextA</td>
        <td>Column2TextA</td>
        <td>Colum3A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='searchable'>
        <td>Column1 Text B</td>
        <td>Column2TextB</td>
        <td>Colum3B</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what I'm talking about, but I have been trying to stay away from For Each loops, in favor for directly selecting (mass) elements/objects through jQuery, for performance reasons. (<-- My uneducated, probably wrong opinion.)

I opted to add a &nbsp; to the end of each td instead. My search function now works the way I intended.

Comment: Well, I see no reason for that. jQuery uses a forEach loop the other way. You would just be adding complexity to an existing forEach loop.

Comment: I'm sure jQuery selections use forEach loops internally, thus if I used a forEach loop in conjunction with one of these selectors, aren't I looping twice?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how it can be done using your example. Keep in mind that `filter` is still a loop.

Comment: As for your last comment, no it uses one loop either way, but if you're going to add another loop to add a space before each table cell then it would be two.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been looking over your answer and I can't rightly make sense of it. I am a novice so I apologize. Is there anyway to divide the td text collected from each tr by a space through jQuery? .text() lumps it all together because the td's are child elements of each tr, but is there a way to divide each td's text with a space?

Comment: Well, yes but you would be adding an unnecessary loop to the mix. What the above function does is expanded from your own function. But basically it just selects all of the cells then reduces the results based on the RegExp test. If the length of the remaining results is 0 (meaning it didn't match any cells) then that row from will remain in the list, if it is any other number the row will be removed from the list. At the end, any rows that remain in the list of rows will be hidden. I've edited my answer to include a method of prepending a space to each cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.each()` on the `td`'s and add the space:

```
var row = "";
console.log($("#tbl #row td").each(function(){
    row += " "+$(this).text();
}));
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yee43bcs/)

Or simply cycle through the `td`'s of each `tr` and use the regex on those items. In that case inside the `.each` you would just apply the regex on `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 0):

I elected to take my own answer, and add a non-breaking space `(&nbsp;)` to the end of each `<td>`. I was able to compensate for the offset in the visual structure of the table.

I believe Tiny Giant's answer will work, but I don't believe it was the correct answer for me.

Thanks for the help though!